# Akka, advices on implementation

Tags: scala, akka

I would like to create an app who integrate our (enterprise) specific tools with Slack. For that I can foreseen some *bots* who send events to Slack and a few *commands* who trigger actions.

I would like to use Akka because it is a buzzword and seems nice but don't have any arguments in favor of it. (It is not a problem since I will develop this app alone on my freetime).

But I don't have any experience on how to create an "Actor based application". I already have 3 actors, two to collect `Event`s and one to publish those `Event`s to Slack. Each collector are triggered by a timer, they hold a reference to the publisher and send message to him... that works..

For the *commands* part I din't have anything but can imagine a *listener* (Play http controller) who convert Slack requests to message and send them to one Actor. Ideally, I would like to decouple this *listener* from the Actor who will handle the command.

I would like to have some advices on how to develop this kind of applications where I have actors to collect information on a time basis and other to react to  messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For time based activity, i.e. "ticks" or "heartbeats", the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/howto.html#Scheduling_Periodic_Messages) demonstrates a very good pattern for sending messages to Actors periodically.

For your other need, Actors responding to messages as they come in, this is exactly the purpose of the Actor's receive method.  From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/general/actor-systems.html):

> Actors are objects which encapsulate state and behavior, they
>   communicate exclusively by exchanging messages which are placed into
>   the recipient’s mailbox. In a sense, actors are the most stringent
>   form of object-oriented programming, but it serves better to view them
>   as persons: while modeling a solution with actors, envision a group of
>   people and assign sub-tasks to them, arrange their functions into an
>   organizational structure and think about how to escalate failure (all
>   with the benefit of not actually dealing with people, which means that
>   we need not concern ourselves with their emotional state or moral
>   issues). The result can then serve as a mental scaffolding for
>   building the software implementation.